# Unable to install electron using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I am trying to install electron but it stucks on > node install.js. I have tried many times and left my laptop on for 2 hours but no success. Then I tried **npm install --verbose electron --save-dev** so that I could see stats and what is happening in background. And I realized that it's being downloading with only 10kbps or less speed and after sometime it stucks. Can someone please help me? I have searched many times on internet but didn't find any useful answer that's why I am asking a question here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running (no https):

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

It seems that it worked for [these guys](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11028)

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I just tried using China Mirror and no it's downloading with 150+kbps. I just used **npm set registry https://registery.npm.taobao.org** and it worked for me.

Comment: can you please tell me what could be the problem? was that problem from my side or it was an issue in the repository server?